# Question about relations between two numbers

Tags: factorization, bit-representation

Is there is any relation between numbers' bits when one is divisible  by another?  What is the relation between the bits of 36 and the bit sequences of 9 or 4 or 12, or between 10 (1010)  and 5 (101), or 21 (10101) and 7 (00111)?

Thanks. I am sorry if some sentence is not correct, but I hope you understand what I want.

Comment: you want to know if there is some relationship between the binary representation of a number and its factors?

Comment: @Paul: That is what I understood too.

Comment: factorization is a problem that isn't made easier by any particular numerical representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take the example of 36.

```
36 = 0010 0100
```

`36` is `4 * 9`, that is

```
 4 = 0100
 9 = 1001
```

If you multiply them (like you would on a normal multiplication) you'll have

```
    0100 x
    1001
 --------
    0100
   0000
  0000
 0100
 -------
 0100100
```

So essentially `0100 x 1001 = 0010 0100` (you can repeat the same for any other pair of divisors of course)

Now, is there any special relation that will allow you to get all the divisors of 36 just by looking at its bits? The answer, alas, is no :)

EDIT: there is no KNOWN relation at least but, who knows, in the future maybe some smart mathematician will find one. As of today, the answer is still no.

Comment: What makes you think the answer is "NO"? Do you have a proof lying around somewhere?

Comment: There is a world of mathematical literature on the complexity of integer factorization. It has definitely been proven that there's no "shortcut" to get the divisors of a number by writing it in binary.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: @Dmazzoni. It hasn't been shown yet. People think Integer factorization lies between P and NP-Complete, similar to Graph Isomorphism, but that is all. There is no proof to say that with conviction.

Comment: @Dmazzoni @nico: A more correct answer is, if there *is* a way to quickly figure out the factors just by looking at the number written in binary, none of the world's smartest mathematicians have figured it out yet.

Comment: @Moron: I have a beautiful proof of that but there's not enough space in the comment box to write it.

Comment: @nico: Well then come up with an even more brilliant compression algorithm and post it! While you are working on that, perhaps you can edit your answer to make it correct.

Comment: @Moron: hmmmm... I guess you did not get the reference/joke. See  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#Fermat.27s_conjecture

Comment: @nico: Of course I got the reference. But, at least edit your answer so I can remove the downvote! Since you didn't put a smiley, I didn't either.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is not exactly what you're asking, but it may be helpful. There are many tricks for establishing binary number divisibility by manipulation of bits. For example a binary number is divisible by three if the sum of its even binary bits minus the sum of its odd binary bits all modulus 3 is zero. Here's a link discussing [binary divisibility](http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.math/2006-04/msg01425.html).

Answer (score 1):

So you want to know if you can 'quickly' do [Integer Factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) by just looking at the bits?

Good luck with that!

Comment: +1 Answer is correct and just as legitimate (if not more so) than the question it answers.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, that `a` is a multiple of `b` can be recognized given the binary representions of `a` and `b` (it's what the hardware does when executing the following code

```
boolean isMultiple = a % b == 0;
```

) and hence there is such a relationship.

Ask a more specific question to get a more specific response ...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to see is the number of consecutive 0 in the least significant digits designates the largest power of two that is a factor of your number n.  There are apparently other tests, as DonnyD pointed out (I hadn't known that one) but I expect they're not going scale very well.  If they did, public key cryptography, as it's generally implemented, would quickly become a thing of the past.

That's not to say that such methods can't be discovered / invented.  For instance it's been shown that arbitrarily large numbers can be easily factored  [using quantum methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm), but nobody's ever been actually able to implement a working system.

The bottom line is that we've entrusted our online financial system and national security apparatus to PKI based methods primarily because we assume that factoring numbers is hard for arbitrarily large numbers.  But as Moron seemed to be implying in his answer, you're welcome to give it a whirl.